# Paste without formatting in editor

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, editor

If I copy some rich text onto my clipboard and paste it into a question (or answer), this happens:

[image: Screenshot]

This is pretty annoying if you ever want to copy some text into a question. A workaround I’ve been using for far too long is to paste the text into [Google Keep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Keep) and then copy it into the Stack Exchange app to remove the formatting.

It would be great if pasting would just paste plain text.

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand what the problem is. The text is actually copied with red background? Something else? Please clarify, as most people around here don't use the iOS app so can't know or try to reproduce it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard You can reproduce the same issue in the Android app.

Comment: @ShadowWizard If you copy text with a large monospaced font and a red background onto the clipboard, formatting will be preserved when you paste into the editor. I would prefer formatting to be stripped when the text is pasted.

Comment: Well, but if you submit the question, is the formatting preserved?

Comment: @ShadowWizard When you view the preview or submit the question, the formatting is removed